# Rspec Can't Find Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, tdd

I thought controllers are auto loaded so I can test them with Rspec.

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe QuestionsController do
    it 'next' do
    params = Hash.new
    params[:question_id => 1]
    next_func(params)
  end

end
```

I am receiving the error:

uninitialized constant QuestionsController

Comment: Do you have QuestionsController?

Comment: Which version of rspec are you using?

Comment: I have a QuestionsController. rspec -v says 3.1.5 and gem list says rspec-rails 3.1.0

Comment: we need more info, much more. I suggest to post `spec_helper.rb`, post path to your controller, your QuestionsController.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
RSpec.describe QuestionsController, type: :controller do
  it 'next' do
    params = Hash.new
    params[:question_id => 1]
    next_func(params)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, which was due to the fact that my controllers are within an API.

If that is your case, don't forget to update your controller name inside your test from

```
require 'rails_helper'
    
RSpec.describe UsersController do
    
end
```

to

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::V1::UsersController do

end
```